# Symfony2 sql query with DATE_SUB in hours

Tags: mysql, date, symfony

I want to get from database records from last 12 hours.

I have this in my controler:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT e FROM MainCoreBundle:Event e WHERE e.date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE() , 1, 'DAY')");
        $statement = $query->getResult();
```

But i want to make it for 12 hours and now is for 1 day. And when i change it like this:

```
DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE() , 12, 'HOUR')")
```

I get an error that this method  **DATE_SUB** is only for DAYS and MOUNTHS.

How to get hours? Any other method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to register a custom DQL function!

This can be done with standard doctrine but using a better approach.

```
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

   $results = $qb->select('e')
                 ->from('MainCoreBundle:Event', 'e')
                 ->where('e.date >= :date')
                 ->setParameter('date', new \DateTime('-12 hours'))
                 ->getQuery()
                 ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: I wrote it in controller and when I refresh the site I got 500. Is this method good with symfony 2.1??

Comment: Ok i solved it. This what u write is good. But only thing to change is getOneOrNullResult() to getResult(). THANKS!